# Blank Circle name in Google+

Tags: google-plus

On my Google+ Android app (version 2.1.1.219805) there is a Circle with no name. There's no one in the Circle.

When I check [Google+](http://www.google.com/+) on the web, this mystery Circle is not there. All of my Circles are as they should be.

I've already Force Stopped and cleared the data for the app.

What's going on or, at least, how do I get rid of it?

Comment: I have this problem too. It started soon after the first G+ app was released. I have also removed and reinstalled to no avail. Hopefully they will fix this bug in future updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new version of the app came out today (2.2.0.233662) with "numerous bug fixes" mentioned in the "What's New" text.

This apparently is one of the fixes. Everything is back to normal now.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the resolution you are looking for, but I'd like to share that I have same problem with you.

The blank circle appeared a few days ago.
 There's no blank circle when I check Google+ web page, but there's a mysterious circle with no name (blank name) when I use Google+ android app.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall Google+ app, but it didn't resolve the problem.

Only a few people have reported this problem, and there's a post related to this on Google group too.

I hope it can be fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks for saving me from trying to re-install the app. Can you provide a link to that post?